# Close all but pinned and this?

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible to close all files (tabs) in visual studio except pinned and the currently selected? There are already options for "close all but pinned" and "close all but this".

I find that the option I would need most often would be "close all but pinned and this". Right now I usually close all but pinned then reopen the other file. Yes it doesn't take long but it seems unnecessary.

I would be open to a plugin or extension to achieve this.

Comment: as workaround, pin the currently open one, too, select close all but pinned and unpin the currently open again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command with my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension to pin the current tab, close all unpinned and unpin the current tab:

```
public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
{
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Window.PinTab");
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("OtherContextMenus.EasyMDIToolWindow.CloseAllButPinned");
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Window.PinTab");
}
```